# Cannot use new command inside angular-cli project

Tags: angular-cli

It's quite possible that an angular project was accidentally created inside my home folder in mac osx. So every time I try and create a new project using the angular-cli I receive "You cannot use the new command inside an angular-cli project". I've deleted all associated files with scaffolded project but the error persists. Are there any underlying files that need to be deleted to resolve this error?

Comment: See the response here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236988/cannot-use-new-command-inside-angular-cli-project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere in a parent directory is a Angular-Cli project or where an `ng init` was ran. You have do go up your file structure and find the node_modules folder and delete it along with any associated angular-cli generated files (tslint.json, src folder, protractor.conf.js, node_modules folder , README.md,  angular-cli.json, e2e folder, karma.conf.js,  package.json, .npm/ folder).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add new angular application my using CLI.But I had "package.json" node_modules inside the same folder where I am creating new application folder,after deleting this file and folder.it is working for me.