# cannot use the new command inside an Angular CLI project

Tags: angular-cli

when I try to create new project in angular cli command for **ng new my-app** , but the result is given like **You cannot use the new command inside an Angular CLI project.** I can't create new project in angular cli please help to solve this problem[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPAN5.jpg)

Comment: See this issue :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236988/cannot-use-new-command-inside-angular-cli-project#autocomment98687759

Answer (score 1):

Just remove .angular-cli.json, package.json, package-lock.json from the directory you are trying to run the commands from.
Note: Make sure to make hidden file visible first.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

> You already generated cli project structure in this path `C:\Users\System3` so that the error will be shown. Please check the file `.angular-cli.json` delete it. then try to create new cli project

Note : `.angular-cli.json` is hidden file. So Enable hidden files in your directory then delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and nothing was working out but then when I ran cmd as administrator it worked for me. First, run the Command Prompt as administrator and then create the new project  and it should work. If nothing works just uninstall node and every other file related to it make sure you are using the latest version and run the previous code again.  It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this same issue, except I wasn't in an angular cli project. The solution in my case was to edit package.json (which I'd copied over from another project) & remove the reference to Angular CLI it contained (it was the dev dependencies section for me)

Hope this helps anybody

Answer (score 0):

For me, the .angular-cli.json file was one folder up from my current /dev folder. That file is generated in each new project folder and shouldn't cause issues with sibling projects. However... if it also appears in a parent folder, it can cause this error.

I was in ~/documents/dev and didn't see it (even with showing hidden files). Of course the /dev folder had several project folders in it, and each of those had this file. However, when I went up one folder to ~/documents, I found one there that was quite old. I deleted it and could then run...

```
ng new blah-blah
```

… from the /dev folder to create a new project without getting this error.

Answer (score -1):

See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2818)

> Is there a file called package.json alone in other places ? Deletes it
>   , maybe solve the problem.